# A puzzel about sh and ./

Tags: sh

I have figured that if I want to use`./`to execute a script, I have to run`chmod +x file`first. But why can I execute it by using `sh file` without the `chmod` command? Doesn't `sh` need any executing permission?

Comment: In the second case, it only needs to be readable. See [What is the difference between sh and ./ when invoking a shell script?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/364146/65304)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sh` HAS execution permissions. Well it basically is a symlink to dash.

```
$ ls -l /bin/sh
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root 4 Feb 17  2016 /bin/sh -> dash
```

And dash has execute permissions:

```
$ ls -l /bin/dash
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 154072 Feb 17  2016 /bin/dash
```

All dash has to do is parse the script so the file needs to be readable.

Comment: Then why `./` need execution permission? Doesn't it work like `sh`?

Comment: How would you differentiate between listing the file on screen and executing it contents? There needs to be a way to tell the file to execute and you do that with `./` + executing permissions. (The latter is more a security measure: being able to execute anything is bad).